# Angular 5 - Realtime data from a PHP JSON feed

Tags: angular, angular5

I have been developing with Angular for a while now and some points of RxJS still cause some issues and I tend to get around them using various methods like timeouts or polling using intervals etc, but I have a feeling there is a more elegant solution and I would love to know it so basically here is some questions.

Say you have a Laravel application which is generating JSON from a twitter feed, what is the best way to retrieve these results.

I am thinking using angular http to get the feed.json, then use an Observable.interval to poll the server at regular intervals and use behaviour subject to display the result in almost realtime.

This is not based on anything I am currently working on so I cant supply code, Im just wondering is this the right approach, I remember once upon a time polling the backend server was a frowned upon thing, especially if were talking about an app where 100s/1000s of instances are all polling the feed at the same time simultaneously

or to throw another example into the mix, how about a realtime Ethereum blockchain ticker that monitors the blockchains currently mined blocks, gas price etc.. currently there is an implementation in Angular 1 called EthStats checking into their source code i see here on line 95 that they are updating the view every 300ms [https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats/blob/master/src/js/controllers.js#L95]

Is polling or timeouts the de-facto standard for realtime now ? I see so few (none) tutorials that make use of WebSockets or MQTT in a useful scalable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interval to communicate with your server can be dangerous if your application has a lot of users. Imagine 1m users sending a request to your server every second? It can be really dangerous if not handled a better way.

To solve it, you can use a [Websocket](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting) connection to make the back-end communicate with the front-end when there is new data in the feed, so it will request new data only when there really is.

Laravel has some stuff to help you do it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting

Comment: Cool I was thinking websocket or some other protocol like MQTT could be the way forward. But every example I see out there doesnt really take these things into consideration. everything seems to just show the quick fix "You need data, oh, and you need it in realtime... that will be a polling operation" but i want to see some scalable production ready implementations using Angular and RxJS... I was just using Laravel as an example :)

Comment: Thx, how does the server know there is a new data, before it can push the data to the client?